# Lumen always return 404

Tags: amazon-ec2, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I'm migrating My Lumen Rest Apis to Amazon EC2, and Handler Exception always give me 404.

I can confirm it goes throught bootstrap/app.php

But when it goes into routes.php, it doesn't go to the main /:

```
$app->get('/',function() use ($app){

return "hello";
});
```

It seems it doesn't recognize / nor anyroute I have in my routes.php

It always end in app/Exceptions/Handler

```
 public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof HttpException ) {

        return response()->json(["NOTFOUND",$e->getStatusCode()],$e->getStatusCode()); // <!-- Get me 404
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Any Idea???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Anwser is described here :

[Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/lumen/always-404-sorry-the-page-you-are-looking-for-could-not-be-found)

Edit your index.php file

```
$app->run();
```

to

```
$app->run($app['request']);
```